# Chrome 84 Cipher Suite IIS 8

Tags: windows, google-chrome, iis, chromium

I'm running into an issue with some code that I have that leverages websockets. In chrome 84, it's not allowing me to run websockets, severing the connection and showing this in the 'Security' tab. Everything else on the security tab looks good EXCEPT:

Connection - obsolete connection settings
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, RSA, and 3DES_EDE_CBC with HMAC-SHA1.
RSA key exchange is obsolete. Enable an ECDHE-based cipher suite.
3DES_EDE_CBC is obsolete. Enable an AES-GCM-based cipher suite.

I'm working with our infrastructure folks to really understand what this means - and have tried a few iterations of the configuration (local group policy, then the SSL Cipher Suite Order) to no success. What I'm trying to understand is where I would look to actually see WHAT cipher I can/should run. Is it part of the OS, or SSL Certificate that IIS is using? I keep running into comments about running IIS Crypto - but would be reluctant to let a third party app take care of my Crypto needs without even knowing what the server is capable of running.

Comment: Reproduce the issue on a non production machine, and then use IIS Crypto to manipulate the settings with Process Monitor analyzing registry key changes. That should tell you what keys are involved and then on your production machine you can only manipulate those keys without IIS Crypto.

Comment: MS network monitor can help you monitor the SSL communication between client and server side. It seems that chrome require to get SSL negotiation loaded under specific cipher suite. You can manual set the cipher setting with registry key.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245030/how-to-restrict-the-use-of-certain-cryptographic-algorithms-and-protoc